# Cannot get EMail of Person or Group field from a list using PnP JS?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp

I used SPFx (1.10) Yeoman generator with SharePoint Online version.

I created a column with "Person and Group" field and tried to get an item detail from a list by using PnP JS version 2.0.7:

```
import { sp } from '@pnp/sp/presets/all';

const data: any = await sp.web.lists
      .getByTitle(`ItemList`)
      .items
      .getById(id)
      .select(
        'Person_x0020_or_x0020_Group/Title',
        'Person_x0020_or_x0020_Group/Id',
        'Person_x0020_or_x0020_Group/Created',
        'Person_x0020_or_x0020_Group/EMail'
      )
      .expand(
        'Person_x0020_or_x0020_Group',
      )
      .get();

console.log('ACTION RESULT', data)
```

In my expectation the result will be:

```
[
   {
      Created: "2016-07-17T06:56:04Z",
      Id: 21,
      Title: "Person1 Members",
      EMail: "person1@<tenant-url>.com",
      odata.id: "4f18225b-1687-4fc7-b7a9-2f660ec2815e",
      odata.type: "SP.Data.UserInfoItem",
   },
   ...
]
```

But the console will return status code 500 and print an error:

`"Cannot get value for projected field Person_x0020_or_x0020_Group_x005f_EMail."`

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user does not have an email address (the administrator has not assigned EXchagne license to this user), the requst will go wrong.

Below is my test:

```
const item= sp.web.lists.getByTitle("listname").items.getById(8).select("Customer/Title","Customer/ID","Customer/EMail").expand("Customer").get();
console.log("item: ", item);
```

User has email:
[image]

User has no email:
[image]

More reference:

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/6d02ed74-7c73-43c5-a90f-eb7bca2e7235/error-cannot-get-value-for-projected-field-approversx005femail-how-to-handle-it-?forum=onlineservicessharepoint